Own Shader implementation for maven-shade-plugin & java 21
We're using the Using your own Shader implementation for maven-shade-plugin as described here   to rename some files.
Our versions are:

plexus-component-annotations & plexus-component-metadata -> 2.1.1,
maven-shade-plugin -> 3.5.1

It is working wel for java 17. We're upgrading the project to java 21. We're not able to build the projects due to the plexus incompatibility with java 21.
Checking the plexus documentation we see that the project has been deprecated and we should use sisu instead.
We do understand we have to use the   https://github.com/eclipse-sisu/sisu-project  project.
We've followed the Plexus-to-JSR330 manual to migrate the annotations for our shader hint class.
When packaging the project, we see that the \META-INF\sisu\javax.inject.Named  is generated, but later, when executing the maven-shade-plugin, we have the error unable to lookup own Shader implementation with hint: 'our_hint_shader_class'
We've seen that the issue is  related with the  components.xml file that is not generated as it is done with plexus-component-metadata. Is there any way to create it? Or some option to make the maven-shade-plugin work with Sisu?
